# how to update one drop down list depending to another one

Tags: ajax

I have 2 drop down lists ,
firstly i used on load to fill the first list , and i didn't face proplems on it.
but when the first list's value change , i want to fill the second list depending on the new value.
but however i changed the options of the first list , the second list is still empty,  what is the proplem in my code ?
in html file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#select1').change(function(){                                                
             $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'SubmitHomework.php',
                data: 'q='+$('#select1').val(),
                success: function(msg[])
                {  for(var i=0 ; i<msg.length ; i++)
                     $('#select2').append(msg[i]); }
                });
             });
         });
</script>
```

in php file(fill the second drop down list part)

```
    $connected = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "web");
   $q = $_GET['q'];
    if($q != "")
    {
      $sql2 = "SELECT homeworkTitle, homeworkID FROM homework, hwcourse WHERE cTitle='csc212' AND hwID = homeworkID";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($connected,$sql2);
     while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))                
     {    $array1[]= "<option value='$row3[homeworkID]'> $row3[homeworkTitle] </option>"; }
         return $array1; }
```

Comment: why is the question related to php if you want to update the select elements using javascript?

Comment: because the options in select list is from my database

Comment: no, your question is not about selecting from a database. the question is generally about changing DOM elements using javascript.

Comment: And btw, it's really not clear from your question what is the problem. I it with the request? with the change? with the update? or you have an SQL problem? Remove from the question everything that is **not** related to your problem, leave only the problem, this way you will get help much faster.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/5QPq5/

Comment: @Exception thank you very much .. i got it now

Comment: @Exception, `live` is deprecated, I really advise to stop using it.